# How to label raster cells using ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, labeling

I want to generate a small sample raster (eg. euclidean distance or cost distance) to explain the method of cost-distance analysis, and I'd like to label the pixels with the corresponding cost-value.

I already tried to lay a fishnet over the raster in ArcGIS, but I didn't find a good way to copy the values into the attribute table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Convert your raster to points with [ArcGIS Raster To Point Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000007000000)
2. Label the point layer. Use a transparent symbol for your point layer.

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS you could use gdal2xyz to make a text file containing xyz triplets:

```
gdal2xyz.py raster.xxx textfile.txt
```

This will produce a space-delimited text file that can be imported to QGIS as points.